# CSS and PHP to run exec and return to original page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Kind of a newbie to web coding, and I am trying to achieve something simple:
Show a page with a big button image on it, and when clicked, it will execute a simple command line on my Raspberry Pi. After the exec is done, I would like to return to the same page ready for another press of the button.

So, I am using the following:

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['trigger']) && $_GET['trigger'] == 1)
{
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    exec('<something>');
    usleep(1000000);
    exec('<something>');
    header("Location: push.php");
    exit;
}

?>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <a href='push.php?trigger=1' class="btn"></a>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

This works, however, after the exec finishes, the browser is not redirected back to the original page, or it does, but the url is:

```
http://10.0.0.1/push.php?trigger=1
```

Which have the GET paramerts. Therefore, I cannot click the button again, until I either hit the back button or refresh button on the browser.

Any thoughts...?

Comment: your `push.php` page would have to redirect the browser back to whatever file your above script is in, e.g. `header("Location: your_other_script.php");`. The presence of query parameters on that url would not affect whether a button/link on the page is clickable.

Comment: By "cannot click the button again," do you just mean the page is not updating because it was cached? Hitting refresh makes the browser dump the cache and download the new version of the page. Clicking the link again pulls from the cache. If you want the page to not be cached, set no-cache headers.

Comment: The push.php is the same file above. It serves both to show the push button and to handle the click. Should I seperate the php and html to 2 different files?

Comment: @developerwjk, the problem is not the cache, but seems to be the fact that the get parameters are still there means (for unknown reason) the page does not respond to my clicks. If  i click back, the url becomes the good (i.e. the expected) one which is push.php, without the get parameters and then everything works.

Comment: That should only happen when `#` is present in the url, like with `push.php?trigger=1#`.  Maybe your browser is messed up.

Comment: Not necessary to separate your html from the php handlers. That's a good way to keep stuff together. I would recommend `echo`ing something right before your `header()` call to see if your code is even getting down that far. Have you checked your error logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a more elegant solution could be to use ajax, i see that you already have jquery so you could include a script with this code

```
var button = $('.btn')
$(document).on('click', '.btn', function(){
    button.css('display', 'none');
    $.get('push.php?trigger=1', function(){
        button.css('display', 'block');
    });
});
```

this will call the site without caring about the response and it will execute your script, i would suggest using a `<button></button>` tag instead of `<a></a>` to avoid redirection

If you would like to improve your code further i would separate the script from the html and maybe call it with POST instead of GET

Comment: Thank you Roberto. I eventfully ended up using ajax is a different way.